# using (SqlConnection), scope and connection pooling

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I've only recently learned about this mechanism of connection pooling and discovered that I had been coding my SQL connections all wrong. I used to maintain a global SQL connection against which all `SqlCommands` would execute.

So I'm now making large scale changes to my existing code. There were no fewer than 260 `SqlCommands` referencing the global `SqlConnection` which I am now busy wrapping with

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(globally_stored_connection_string))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    // SqlCommand comes here
}
```

I suppose it's still a bit of a paradigm shift I have to make, this business of closing a connection only to open a new one shortly after, trusting the connection pooling to take care of the overhead. With that in mind I need to decide now how to wrap `SqlCommands` that are called many times inside a loop. Would appreciate your thought on which of the following sections of code are preferred (of course there's much more to my `SqlCommands` than just this but these are simple examples to illustrate the question).

**OPTION A:**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
{
    foreach(int number in numberList)
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here using number from foreach loop", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

**OPTION B:**

```
foreach (int number in numberList)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here using number from foreach loop", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered rewriting the code such that you don't need to loop at all? Making 1 SQL statement do the work for you?

Comment: And what about transactions? I mean, if these commands should work or fail as a single unit  you need to consider also to wrap everything inside a TransactionScope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are missing Option C, which to me would make the most sense:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here using number from foreach loop", sqlConnection))
    {
        foreach (int number in numberList)
        {
            //Modify command parameters if needed
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

This has the least overhead for executing commands. Constructing a `SqlCommand` object isn't *very* expensive, but it isn't free either. Here we can reuse it, if possible.

Comment: One could argue that doing it in a *single* call to `ExecuteNonQuery` would yield the least overhead, however, +1

Comment: @James yes, if it's possible to get rid of the loop entirely, or use `SqlBulkCopy`, it would definitely be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    foreach(int number in numberList)
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here using number from foreach loop", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to open the connection once in this block of code.

While it's good to close the connection as soon as you're done with it, you don't have to take it to the extreme and open a connection for each transaction. It's enough to open it once if your executing several commands one after another. Even with connection pooling there is some overhead in opening a new connection. It's enough if you don't keep it for *too* long.